# ebpf tail call didn't work even bpf code is loaded successfully

Tags: c, go, ebpf, bpf

```
#include "bpf/bpf_helpers.h"
#include <linux/bpf.h>
char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") jump_table = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_PROG_ARRAY,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .max_entries = 100,
};

SEC("xdp_1")
int test_func(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
  bpf_printk("tail call\n");
  return XDP_PASS;
}

SEC("xdp")
int xdp_pass_func(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
  __u32 zero = 0;
  bpf_tail_call(ctx, &jump_table, zero);
  bpf_printk("tail call failed\n");
  return XDP_PASS;
}
```

when i look `cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe`, it shows `tail call failed`,but i don't know whats wrong,here is my load code

```
func main() {
    if err := rlimit.RemoveMemlock(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    var obj aclObjects
    err := loadAclObjects(&obj, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    err = obj.JumpTable.Put(uint32(0), uint32(obj.TestFunc.FD()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    link, err := netlink.LinkByName("ens33")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    err = netlink.LinkSetXdpFd(link, obj.XdpPassFunc.FD())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
}
```

the bpf code can be loaded, but it seems some thing wrong with tail_call，i wrote it according to linux source code，someone can help me?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Did you check with bpftool that both programs are loaded (both of type XDP), and that the prog_array map is correctly updated with a reference to test_func?

Answer (score 1):

As you realised and mentioned in your answer, the file descriptor referencing the program will indeed be closed when the loader exits.

If nothing else references the program, it is unloaded. What can hold such a reference?

- Said file descriptor, as long as the loader remains open.
- If the program is attached to certain hooks (for example: networking hooks), it remains in place even after the loading process exists.
- If the program is pinned, it's kept as well. This is the very purpose of pinning a program to the virtual BPF file system. See [this reference for some details on pinning to the bpffs](https://ebpf.io/blog/ebpf-updates-2021-01#did-you-know-ebpf-virtual-filesystem), or more generally, [this post on the lifetime of eBPF objects](https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/bpf/blog/2018/08/31/object-lifetime.html).

What you want is to pin your program before your loader exits (It seems you use goebpf? Apparently the library has [a `Pin()` function](https://github.com/dropbox/goebpf/blob/d54e462ac3892c8f0774fabef8b9f987abaf8eac/ebpf.go#L29), which should probably help).

Answer (score 0):

i find the problem that prog fd will be closed when loader program exit, so i keep the program blocked and tail call works fine, i don't know why fd closed is a problem, hoping someone can answer

Comment: This reads more like a comment on your question than as an answer; can you try moving it to be a comment, please?

Comment: The fd will indeed be closed when the loader exits. If nothing else references the program, it is unloaded. What can hold such a reference? 1) the fd, as long as the loader is open 2) if the program is attached to certain hooks, it remains in place 3) if the program is pinned, it's kept as well. See [this reference](https://ebpf.io/blog/ebpf-updates-2021-01#did-you-know-ebpf-virtual-filesystem). What you want is to pin your program before your loader exits (goebpf seems to have [a `Pin()` function](https://github.com/dropbox/goebpf/blob/d54e462ac3892c8f0774fabef8b9f987abaf8eac/ebpf.go#L29))